# How to set the path for python for docker installing from image ubuntu

Tags: python, docker

I made the image from `ubuntu:18.04` and install python.

However when I did this in docker-compose

```
command: python manage.py runserver
```

it shows the path error.

Maybe I didn't set the path??

but how I set the path for docker user??

```
ERROR: for django  Cannot start service django: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"python\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.


FROM ubuntu:18.04

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install emacs wget

RUN apt-get -y install apache2-dev mysql-client
RUN apt-get -y install mysql-server libmysqlclient-dev

RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
RUN apt-get install -y python3.7

RUN apt-get install -y python-pip
RUN pip install uwsgi django mysqlclient tensorflow_hub django-mysql django-extensions djangorestframework django-filter requests_oauthlib mecab-python3 neologdn gensim janome --no-input
RUN pip install keras tensorflow==1.14.0 --no-cache-dir --no-input

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code

ADD ./src /code/
```

Comment: If you get a debugging shell based on your image (`docker run --rm -it yourimage bash`), and look around in `/usr/bin`, what do you see?

Comment: log  in image and did `python manage.py runserver` -> `File "manage.py", line 18
    ) from exc`
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I found and my python is somehouw 2.7, I even installed the RUN apt-get install -y python3.7

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this in two ways (works for me):

in docker-compose add:

```
command: bash -c 'python manage.py runserver'
```

or you can add CMD command in your Dockerfile:

```
CMD: python manage.py runserver
```